# C++ async HTTP library to download files

Tags: c++, http

Looking for a C++ async HTTP library so I can download some zip files from a website. I would prefer it be really easy to use. Like DownloadFile(website_zip_path) where a callback is fired when the download is complete, kind of easy. Anyone know of anything like this? Does not have to be cross platform (win based). The ease of use is more what I'm worried about here as some other libraries I've seen seem to make it more complicated that it seems like it should be.

[EDIT]
Has anyone ever used http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/http_backgroundThread.asp
Might give that a try. Seems very simple and to the point. Nevermind, looks like I have to pay for that. Bah.

Comment: You can just run `UrlDownloadToFile` in separate thread(s)

Comment: That does seem like an easy function indeed. Just not thrilled about having to deal with threads myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your solution is for Windows then you may try using WinInet.

[SAMPLE: How to Use AsyncHTTP to Call WinInet APIs Asynchronously](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275046)

[Using WinInet HTTP functions in Full Asynchronous Mode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822/Using-WinInet-HTTP-functions-in-Full-Asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

You could use boost asio.
I think it is simple to use and for your use case there is also an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)

Comment: I saw that before but seems like a decent amount of code to do something that seems like it could be done much easier with probably 5 lines of code or so.